# Visual Studio Server Explorer not closing sqlsrvr.exe process

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework, database-connection

I have this 'issue' since a long time and I am really wondering if this is just me or if there actually is a way of preventing the following:

**UPDATED**
In Visual Studio, when using the Server Explorer on a .mdf database, in a Entity Framework Code first approach project whenever I am opening the Database manually to see the data of certain tables (clicking on Show table data), it seems that even when I close the connection like this:

[image]

the database connection stays open somehow in the background. 
I am getting "... the Database is currently in use ..." error if wanting to debug afterwards, after closing the connection, even when restarting the solution.

**When I close all sqlservr.exe process(es) in the Task manager that does the trick.**

Note that this is a local solution and a local database (.mdf) i am using for testing purposes. Nothing or no one else is using this solution.

I am quite sure this is not the behavior it should have right?
What am I doing wrong or what can I do to not have this behavior if this is not by default?

Thank you in advance for any feedback!

Comment: Are you sure the connection is from your application? Check sys.dm_exec_sessions to be sure it's coming from your side (host_name, program_name/client_interface_name might help) or sp_who2. Also, are you using [Connection Pooling?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) EF uses it by default.

Comment: I edited my original post. I don't have the sys.dm_exec_sessions in the .mdf or any SP for that matter. I am pretty sure it is my connection that stays open but don't I added the Pooling=False; and that seems to do the trick ... Thank you for mentioning this @Rasnick you rock!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the "Pooling" flag in the connect string set to false:

```
Pooling=False
```

**However**, this might not be the best option in a productive environment:

> Connection pooling reduces the number of times that new connections must be opened. The pooler maintains ownership of the physical connection. It manages connections by keeping alive a set of active connections for each given connection configuration. Whenever a user calls Open on a connection, the pooler looks for an available connection in the pool. If a pooled connection is available, it returns it to the caller instead of opening a new connection. When the application calls Close on the connection, the pooler returns it to the pooled set of active connections instead of closing it. Once the connection is returned to the pool, it is ready to be reused on the next Open call. (...) [SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling)

Comment: Could not agree more on that. I am aware of this property but boy I did not think this had to do anything with this since the debug session was closed and due to the fact that I am looking at the database manually but hey, another thing I have learned and thank you for that!